# How to use accountExpires AD property in python?

Tags: python, active-directory, adsi

I'm using pyad to manipulate AD users in python. I retrieve and use most of user attributes without problem, but when I retrieve accountExpires with:

```
exp_date = aduser.get_attribute('accountExpires',False)
```

`exp_date` is a `COMObject GetEx`. `accountExpires` must be an `int64` and I have no idea how to retrieve a long from this comobject.

Any help?

Comment: Can you post the whole code for accessing AD with python? I need to do nearly the same, but i can't find any good documentation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [problems accessing object \[<COMObject GetEx>\] using python pyad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21520859/problems-accessing-object-comobject-getex-using-python-pyad)

Answer (score 1):

Use the pyadutils module from pyad:

```
from pyad import pyadutils

...

exp_date = aduser.get_attribute('accountExpires',False)
print pyadutils.convert_datetime
```