# problems accessing object [<COMObject GetEx>] using python pyad

Tags: python, pyad

I'm having problems trying to access the active directory user attribute using pyad. Here is my code:

```
user = pyad.aduser.ADUser.from_cn("tuser")
print user.get_attribute(lastLogonTimestamp")
```

These are the printed attributes:

```
C:\Users\tuser\Desktop\docb0t>python docb0t.py
[<COMObject GetEx>]
```

I have no idea how to retrieve the value off that object. How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into this same issue and after a little digging figured out the answer. You need to run the attribute through the pyadutils.convert_datetime function.

```
print pyadutils.convert_datetime(user.get_attribute('lastLogonTimeStamp', False))
```

### Enjoy!

TriSkulL

Comment: hey man  sorry for the late response but until now i got to work on the project again.  it did work...  thanks lots

Comment: For some reason I get: NameError: name 'pyadutils' is not defined
When I include it with from pyad import pyadutils, aduser, I get this error: OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Comment: Figured it out. the "False" thing in the code was apparently very important. Thank you!